Change title color in Docusaurus
On the site homepage, there is the "title" text which is the big text on the banner. By default, it is white on light theme and black on dark theme, and I want to swap this. Is there a variable I can set in custom.css that will change the color of this text to be different in both the light and dark themes?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

is it resolved?
